# Playwright simultaneous jobs

Tags: docker, gitlab, playwright

I have the below scenario to be done using playwright & gitlab:

I have many branches where the deployment can happen and wherever it happens, it should trigger a set of tests using playwright automation. Once testing is completed, the associated report should be pushed to gitlab as an output/artifact. ***The idea is to enable simultaneous tests initiated by multiple users from multiple branches. And for this to happen, I need the test report from each of these containers (generated once the test is completed) to be available in the gitlab job for easy reference.***

What I have done:
I am deploying a docker container which contains the official playwright image + test cases required from gitlab.
Once the docker container is deployed, a test case would automatically run (as I have npm run test provided in the docker file), and a report would be generated inside playwright-report folder.
I have added a new stage in YAML file where I am trying to login to the VM (where docker container is running) and use docker cp command. A snippet of the job is provided below:

```
fetch_report:
 stage: fetch_report
 script:
   - echo -e "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
   - echo $SSH_KEY >> /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
   - echo -e "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" >> /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
   - chmod 600 /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
   - cat /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
   - mkdir -p $CI_PROJECT_DIR/playwright_report_$CI_PIPELINE_ID/
   - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
   - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
   - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"'
   - ssh -i /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 deploy@$VM_IP "docker cp playwright-runner-1:/usr/src/app/playwright-report/. $CI_PROJECT_DIR/playwright_report_$CI_PIPELINE_ID/"
 artifacts:
   paths:
     - playwright-report/
 rules:
   - when: manual
```

While executing the above snippet in gitlab, it fails with an error **"invalid output path: directory "/builds/org-name/qa/Quality-Assurance" does not exist""**

I am looking out for documentations on this and I cant find any so far. Any help would be really appreciated.